# GPIO Level Triggered Understanding

Tags: arm, embedded, interrupt, gpio, interrupt-handling

I have recently started working on GPIO Interrupts both edge triggered as well as level triggered. I implemented edge triggered and that seems to be working fine, but for level triggered interrupts, I am a little confuzed.

Suppose, I pull the **pin low for initial state** and configure the pin as **High level triggered Interrupt**. So, if I will now connect Vcc to my pin, I will receive an interrupt. That's fine. My question is now if I keep my Vcc continuously connected to this pin, should the interrupts keep on coming or should it trigger only once?
Note: I have cleared the pending interrupt in Gpio Handler Interrupt routine.

In case any good reference document is available, please provide the link also, I want to dig deeper into it. Thanks

Comment: What happened to learning by experimenting?

Answer (score 3):

> should the interrupts keep on coming or should it trigger only once?

This is generally the main trait of level-triggered interrupts: As soon as the input line is on trigger level and the interrupt flag is clear, an interrupt is triggered.

So if your GPIO line is constantly at trigger level, the interrupt will trigger initially - And as soon as you clear the interrupt flag in the ISR, the interrupt will trigger again - Probably not very useful, but depending on what you want. In such a system, your code will continuously execute the ISR and nothing else.

Comment: *"And as soon as you clear the interrupt flag..."* -- And enable interrupts.    *"your code will continuously execute the ISR"* -- Instead of "code", don't you mean the processor?

Comment: You may of course change the level sense in the ISR (from high to low).  Your ISR will need state and you risk missing a transition due to latency of the ISR executing and transition events (ie minimum pulse width).  For this reason, people usually stick to the edge trigger and read the level in the ISR.